# Regular Expression for format

Tags: .net, vb.net

What would be the regular expression in VB.NET for the format `V09.1_22-02-1989`?

```
Dim VP As New Regex(
    "(^[Vv]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(/|_)\d{1,2}(/|-    )\d{1,2}\1(\d{4}|\d{2})$")
```

Comment: You have a `\1` backreference; did you mean `\2`? Make sure to remove the spaces if there really are any, too.

Comment: I want to write regular expression  for format like Version_Date  V08.1_22-03-14 .

Comment: What would be the reg exp for this format V09.1-22.8.14?

Comment: @sudukusolver You can generate the Regex online.,It supports many language.. [http://txt2re.com/ ]

Comment: Are you trying to match this string, validate it or extract specific parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this and it work

```
^[Vv]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\_\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-(\d{4}|\d{2})$
```

So remember to escape specials caracters

But you have a date in your format so this regex need improvement:

```
 ^[Vv]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\_(3[01]|[12]?\d)\-(1[012]|\d)\-(\d{4}|\d{2})$
```

To respect dates possibilities

Comment: ..thanx..looking for this only